# graphics outside trimmedsize, extra wide headers and footers

Tags: memoir

1. How to place (absolute positioning?) graphics inside and outside trimmedsize (part of image is inside trimmedsize and tiny part is outside)?
2. How to make headers and footers wider than textwidth?
3. How to make headers and footers wider than stockwidth?
4. How to lay 2 pages (left next to right) on one stock material, see image:

[image]